# Windows Service with FileSystemWatcher starts and stops immediately after

Tags: c#, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I am creating a pos app that cannot communicate with my fiscal printer. So I have decided to store a receipt in a text file as Json object and make Windows Service app with FileSystemWatch to check for file updates and forward it to printer. I am using third party library to communicate with the printer. Here is a code of the service:

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var program = new Watcher();
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        program.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[]
        {
            program
        });
    }
    //ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    //ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    //{
    //    new Watcher()
    //};
    //ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

**Watcher.cs**

```
public partial class Watcher : ServiceBase
{

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetServiceStatus(IntPtr handle, ref ServiceStatus serviceStatus);

    public static OICFiscalPrinter printer { get; set; }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ServiceStatus
    {
        public long dwServiceType;
        public ServiceState dwCurrentState;
        public long dwControlsAccepted;
        public long dwWin32ExitCode;
        public long dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
        public long dwCheckPoint;
        public long dwWaitHint;
    };

    public enum ServiceState
    {
        SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,
        SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,
        SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,
        SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,
        SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,
        SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,
        SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007,
    }


    public Watcher()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void CheckReceipt(object e, FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        printer = new OICFiscalPrinter();
        var name = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        string text = null;
        try
        {
            text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(name + "\\Pictures\\test.txt");
            var BasketList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemsOnFacture>>(text);
            printer.PortConfigString = "PortName=COM4;DataBits=8;Speed=9600;" +
                                       "Parity = N; StopBits = 1; FlowControl = X;" +
                                       "ReadTimeout = 6000;" +
                                       "WriteTimeout = 500; UseReadBuffer = 1";
            printer.Active = true;
            var t = printer.Open();
            if (!t) return;
            printer.OpenReceipt();
            foreach (var item in BasketList)
            {
                printer.ReceiptItem(item.ItemName, item.VatFee == 5 ? "B" : item.VatFee == 8 ? "A" : "D",
                    (decimal)item.PriceBrutto,
                    item.Amount, "unit", (decimal)item.PriceBruttoSum);
            }
            printer.CloseReceipt((decimal)BasketList.Sum(w => w.PriceBruttoSum),
                (decimal)BasketList.Sum(w => w.PriceBruttoSum));
            printer.Close();
            File.Delete(name + "\\Pictures\\test.txt");
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //Start Logic here
        var serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus
        {
            dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING,
            dwWaitHint = 100000
        };


        this.fileSystemWatcher1 = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.fileSystemWatcher1)).BeginInit();
        // 
        // fileSystemWatcher1
        // 
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        var name = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        fileSystemWatcher1 = new FileSystemWatcher(name + "\\Pictures", "test.txt")
        {
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
            IncludeSubdirectories = false,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
        };


        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

        this.fileSystemWatcher1.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.CheckReceipt);

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.fileSystemWatcher1)).EndInit();

        // Update the service state to Running.
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }

    private FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher1;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // 
        // Watcher
        // 
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.ServiceName = "WATTOFP";

    }

    #endregion
}
```

**ProjectInstaller.cs**

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // serviceProcessInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
        // 
        // serviceInstaller1
        // 
        this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "WATTO Fiscal Printer";
        this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = "WATTO Fiscal Printer";
        this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "WATTOFP";
        this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
        this.serviceInstaller1});

    }

    #endregion

    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;
    private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;
}
```

The problem is the fact that after installation when I try to run the service it starts and immediately stops as the warning appears. How can I make the service run and the watch the file for the changes?

Comment: Did you check the windows event log? There should be an exception logged. Additionally did you debug the service?

Comment: Any reason you're manually updating service status? All of that work should be done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that service by default is running under system account. Thus user folder is not what you're expecting and there is no file there.

Usually when service cannot be started, there should be a error with exception in event log. Please post it here for further assistance.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually a problem. The service looked for a file in a wrong directory as it was running under system account. That folder was just a testing location but it was a lesson for me not to pick the locations so carelessly!